# APEX ORACLE PROCEDURE LOOP WITH apex_string.split

Tags: oracle-apex

Hi im using Oracle APEX 22.1.0.

In my procedure im using loop with apex_string.split

and data comes like  (data1,data2,data3,data4) to P_EMPIDS

i want loop each data rows with update table

```
   LOOP      
    select column_value INTO L_EMPIDS
    from table(apex_string.split(P_EMPIDS, ','));
   UPDATE NB_ASSET_CODE SET OWNER_ID = P_ASSET_2 WHERE COMPANY_ID = L_COMPANY_ID AND 
   ASSET_CODE = L_EMPIDS;

END LOOP;
```

how can i loop? this loop dont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you know what `p_asset_2` and `l_company_id` are, then you'd

```
DECLARE
  p_asset_2 ...
  l_company_id ...
BEGIN
   FOR cur_r
      IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE as l_empids
            FROM TABLE (apex_string.split (p_empids, ',')))
   LOOP
      UPDATE nb_asset_code
         SET owner_id = p_asset_2
       WHERE     company_id = l_company_id
             AND asset_code = cur_r.l_empids;
   END LOOP;
END;
```